# Add a foreign key to an existing rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails 4 app.

I have two tables, one for 'scope' and one for 'data'. Data belongs to scope. I forgot to add a foreign key when I set up data and I'm trying to write a migration to add one now.

I have created a change table, but the migration I've written isn't working.

I can't follow the rails guides example because it isn't consistent with the experience I'm having in my setup (not sure why).

The migration I have is:

```
class AddFKeyToData < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

    add_foreign_key :data, :scopes

  end
end
```

Please can you help me identify the problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rollback this migration by:

```
 rake db:rollback
```

Then go into your migration and edit `add_foreign....`

to:

```
add_column :data, :scope_id, :integer
```

Should work!

Comment: Thanks John. Does that mean I don't have to tell it that it's a foreign key expressly?

Comment: Its rails magic! Rails recognizes it by itself! But you have to be sure that the first table is called `data` and the key from scope is called `scope_id`. To be 100% sure go into rails project folder and open the `db\schema`! There you can see  your existing migrations! If you are not sure! Simply post it!

Comment: Sorry but there is still a point you have to add to your data model: `belongs_to :scope` and to your scope model: `has_many: datas` Then you can call for example `Scope.first.datas`

Comment: No magic here. It might have been: `add_column :data, :scope, :references` which is more semantic, it actually describes what it is. It does assume an asociation name of `scope` or `scopes` in a model, but even that can be overridden (not recommended though).